# Error in defining Ticker in ESP32 library

Tags: library, esp32

I'm using the exact piece of code in my ESP8266 library (which works OK ), but when used in a ESP32 library- I got an error:

This is the relevant code snip:

```
void myIOT32::_feedTheDog()
{
  _wdtResetCounter++;
  if (_wdtResetCounter >= _wdtMaxRetries)
  {
    sendReset("Dog goes woof");
  }
}
void myIOT32::_startWDT()
{
  wdt.attach(1, std::bind(&myIOT32::_feedTheDog, this)); // Start WatchDog
}

void myIOT32::sendReset(char *header)
{
  char temp[150];

  sprintf(temp, "[%s] - Reset sent", header);

  if (useSerial)
  {
    Serial.println(temp);
  }
  if (strcmp(header, "null") != 0)
  {
    pub_msg(temp);
  }
  delay(1000);
  ESP.restart();
}
```

and this is the error:

```
/home/guy/Documents/git/Arduino/libraries/myIOTesp32/myIOTesp32.cpp: In member function 'void myIOT32::_startWDT()':
/home/guy/Documents/git/Arduino/libraries/myIOTesp32/myIOTesp32.cpp:333:55: error: no matching function for call to 'Ticker::attach(int, std::_Bind_helper<false, void (myIOT32::*)(), myIOT32*>::type)'
   wdt.attach(1, std::bind(&myIOT32::_feedTheDog, this)); // Start WatchDog
                                                       ^
```

Answer (score 4):

ESP32 ticker attach functions take pure function pointers with at max one argument type -- not a `std::function`/ `std::_Bind_helper` that `std::bind` produces.

See code and types at https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/Ticker/src/Ticker.h#L38.

For the ESP8266 however, they do use a `std::function`:

https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/Ticker/src/Ticker.h#L36

And that's why it works on ESP8266 and not on ESP32 -- either adapt the `Ticker` library or rework your own code to not use member functions of classes.

Edit: You can easily rewrite your code to use a static helper function with one argument (the watchdog object itself) which then just calls the member function of that object. For this to work, the **called function must be public**. So a rewrite like

```cpp
static void watchdog_timer_triggered_helper(myIOT32* watchdog) {
   //needs to be public!
   watchdog->_feedTheDog();
}

void myIOT32::_feedTheDog()
{
  _wdtResetCounter++;
  if (_wdtResetCounter >= _wdtMaxRetries)
  {
    sendReset("Dog goes woof");
  }
}
void myIOT32::_startWDT()
{
  wdt.attach(1, &watchdog_timer_triggered_helper, this); // Start WatchDog
}

void myIOT32::sendReset(char *header)
{
  char temp[150];

  sprintf(temp, "[%s] - Reset sent", header);

  if (useSerial)
  {
    Serial.println(temp);
  }
  if (strcmp(header, "null") != 0)
  {
    pub_msg(temp);
  }
  delay(1000);
  ESP.restart();
}
```

Since both the ESP32 and ESP8266 versions implement the

```cpp
    template<typename TArg>
    void attach(float seconds, void (*callback)(TArg), TArg arg)
```

templated function this should work on both platforms now.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. Can you share an example how to rework ?

Comment: @Guy.D see update.

Comment: @Maximillian  - thank you for you answer. I'm afraid your it a bit more than I understand :( , and I do not like to copy an answer without fully understand. Can you please explain more, or perhaps a more simple answer ( sorry... )

Comment: @Guy.D didn't you write the initial code with `std::bind`, which is more complex than the function pointer used in the answer? Anyways I suggest reading up on C++ templates (`attach()` is a templated function), pure function pointers and `std::function` in C++. I'd take some quiet lengthy text to explain that fully in my answer o_o.

Comment: to be honest, when I found that answer for 8266, I just took it as a given solution without knowing how `bind` work for every detail.... ( shame me :) )....

Comment: @Maximillian - Well, after a long look up ( from almost a month ) I couldn't find any exaplining example to understand your solution ( not the template part ). Can you please refer ?